# Parse error: syntax error, ... expecting T_STRING

Tags: php, syntax

I am having a problem with the following bit of php:

```
<?php 
  $pageTitle = \"Page 1";
  include(\"Header.php\");
?>
```

I get the this syntax error:

> *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING*

Error is on line two. If I had a `'\'` before the second quote mark, I get the following error message for line two:

> *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING in /home/maxster/scc.maxworks.org/p_404.php on line 2*

Can anyone explain what's happening?

Comment: Why do you put slashes before the quotes? BTW, lol'd @ `donkeychunks`

Comment: I put slashes before initially because that was how the the tutorial I was attempting did it. I am a newb, I didn't know better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the / on line two. It wants a string, so just "Page 1" will do.

remove all the slashes as well.

Comment: Thank you - this also helped and i wanted to thank you as well Razor for your help.

Comment: I'd like too but i don't have a high enough reputation yet to do so on stackOverflow. If I could I would. When I do I will :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that using backslash before quotes means, that they are taken as part of the string, so you're actually broking the syntax of your code. One case you can use this is for example, if you want to print quotes inside string:

```
<?php
echo "the french word \"lundi\" means \"monday\" in english";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up escaping quotes within strings and strings. This is a normal string:

```
$pageTitle = "A string";
```

If you want your string to contain quotation marks, you need to escape them using `\` like this:

```
$pageTitle = "I like the band \"U2\" very much!";
```

Please note that in PHP you can change the double quotes to single quotes. The following four statements are valid:

```
$pageTitle = 'I like the band "U2" very much!';
$pageTitle = 'I like the band \'U2\' very much!';
$pageTitle = "I like the band 'U2' very much!";
$pageTitle = "I like the band \"U2\" very much!";
```

Please note how the quotes need to be escaped!

The difference is that when the string starts with double quotes, inline variables are evaluated, while this is not the case for single quotes:

```
$bandName = "U2";
$pageTitle1 = 'I like the band $bandName very much!';
$pageTitle2 = "I like the band $bandName very much!";

echo $pageTitle1 . "<br />";
echo $pageTitle2;
```

The output of this will be

```
I like the band $bandName very much!
I like the band U2 very much!
```

Comment: Thank you Dittmar - this helped very much. I tried to vote it 'up' but i don't have enough reputation points to do so.

Comment: I'd like too but i don't have a high enough reputation yet to do so on stackOverflow. If I could I would. When I do I will :D